# What is the difference between cropping, resizing and scaling an image?

Tags: image, perl, image-resizing, imlib2

I am using Perl's
[`Image::Imlib2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Imlib2)
package to generate thumbnails from larger images.

I've done such tasks before with several ImageMagick interfaces (PHP, Ruby, Python) and it was relatively easy. I have no prior experience with `Imlib2` and it is a long time since I wrote something in Perl, so I am sorry if this seems naive!

This is what I've tried so far. It is simple, and assumes that scaling an image will keep the aspect ratio, and the generated thumbnail will be an exact miniature copy of the original image.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::Imlib2;

my $dir = 'imgs/*';

my @files = glob ($dir);

foreach my $img ( @files ) {
    my $image = Image::Imlib2->load($img);
    my $cropped_image = $image->create_scaled_image(50, 50);
    $cropped_image->save($img);
}
```

Original image

[image: Original image]

Generated image

[image: Generated image]

My first look at the image tells me that something is wrong. It may be my ignorance on cropping, resizing and scaling, but the generated image is displaying wrongly on small screens.

I've read [*What's the difference between cropping and resizing?*](https://www.shutterstock.com/support/article/What-s-the-difference-between-cropping-and-resizing), and honestly didn't understand anything. Also this one [*Image scaling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling).

Could someone explain the differences between those three ideas, and if possible give examples (preferably with Perl) to achieve better results? Or at least describe what I should consider when I want to create thumbnails?

Comment: Would it help to use the [`Image::Magick`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick) Perl module if you're familiar with that library? It's much more flexible than `Imlib2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use isn't preserving the aspect-ratio.  From [Image::Imlib2::create_scaled_image](http://search.cpan.org/~lbrocard/Image-Imlib2-2.03/lib/Image/Imlib2.pm#create_scaled_image_%28x,_y%29)

> If x or y are 0, then retain the aspect ratio given in the other.

So change the line

```
my $cropped_image = $image->create_scaled_image(50, 50);
```

to

```
my $scaled_image  = $image->create_scaled_image(50, 0);
```

and the new image will be 50 pixels wide, and its height computed so to keep the original aspect-ratio.

Since this is not cropping I've changed the variable name as well.

As for other questions, below is a basic discussion from comments. Please search for tutorials on image processing. Also, documentation of major libraries often have short and good explanations.

---

This is aggregated from comments deemed helpful. Also see **Borodin**'s short and clear answer.

Imagine that you want to draw a picture (of some nice photograph) yourself in the following way. You draw a grid of, say, 120 (horizontally) by 60 (vertically) boxes. So 120 x 60, 720 boxes. These are your "pixels," and each you may fill with only one color. If the photo you are re-drawing is "mostly" blue at some spot, you color that pixel blue. Etc. It is not easy to end up with a faithful redrawing -- the denser the pixels the beter.

Now imagine that you want to draw another copy of this, just smaller. If you make it 20x20 that will be completely different, since it's a square. The best chance of getting it to "look the same" is to pick 2-to-1 ratio (like 120x60), so say 40x20. That's "aspect-ratio." But there is still a problem, since now you have to decide all over again what color to pick for each box, so to represent what is "mostly" on the photo at that spot. There are algorithms for that ("sampling," see your second link). That's involved with "resizing." The "quality" of the obtained drawing clearly must be much worse.

So "resizing" isn't all that simple. But, for us users, we mostly need to roughly know what is involved, and to find out how to use these features in a library. So read documentation. Some uses are very simple, while sometimes you'll have to decide which "algorithm" to let it use, or some such. Again, what I do is *read manuals carefully*.

The basic version of "cropping" is simple -- you just cut off a part of the picture.  Say, remove the first and last 20 columns and the bottom and top 10 rows, and from the initial 120x60 you get a picture of 80x40. This is normally done when outer parts of an image have just white areas (or, worse, black!). So you want to "cut out" the picture itself from the whole image. Many graphics tools can do that on their own, by analyzing the image and figuring out those areas. Or, we select and hit a button.

Comment: thanks @zdim, really thanks for those priceless information.

Comment: @zdim: All of this text should be part of your answer.

Comment: @Borodin  Alright, thank you for advice.  I wasn't sure that it belongs in the answer proper, will incorporate it a little later (it's busy now).  Btw, would you have any idea what the -1 is for -- for that?

Comment: That's fine. I don't what the down vote could be for; it would be rather mean to mark you down because of your comments.

Comment: @marmeladze  Thank you for that supportive comment.  Apparently it got removed (I guess for improper language).  I transferred these comments into the answer.

Comment: thanks -)) it's all up to you. if you want them here, let them stay here.

Comment: Extensive comments with explanations, referred to in the above comments, were transferred into the answer and removed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not certain that you understand the difference between these terms

- Your original image is 752 × 500 pixels
- *Resizing* is a vague term that just means making a picture a different size somehow
- *Scaling* is to change the size of an image proportionally. Scaling your picture down by a factor of ten would result in an image 75 × 50 (it should be 75.2 but we can't have 0.2 of a pixel). Scaling it up would make it bigger

  You have *scaled* your picture to 50 × 50 pixels, which is a vertical scale of 10 (500 ÷ 5) but a horizontal scale of 15 (752 ÷ 50), so it appears squashed horizontally (or stretched vertically)
- *Cropping* is to reduce an image by removing parts of it. To crop your image to 50 × 50 you would choose a 50 × 50 rectangle out of the whole picture and remove the rest. It would be a piece about the size of your monkey's nose, but you can pick any region you wish

**zdim** has shown you how you can call

```
$image->create_scaled_image(0, 50)
```

so that the height, or y-dimension, is reduced to 50, while the width, or x-dimension, is scaled *by the same factor*. That will result in a thumbnail 75 × 50 as above

I hope that helps

As I said in my comment, there is an
[`Image::Magick`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick)
Perl module if you would prefer to be back on familiar ground

Answer (score 0):

Resizing and scaling is the same; you just change the size of the image. You can make it smaller or bigger.

Depending on the interface, you have to give either the new dimensions or a scaling factor for the operation. A factor less than or greater than 1.0 would make the image smaller or bigger. Smaller images are created by *subsampling* and bigger images by *interpolation*.

Cropping is very simple. You select a rectangular region of an image and that's your new image. It's like using scissors.

In your code example the image is named `cropped_image` although it is created through scaling, or resizing.

The output image is an image of size 50 x 50 pixels. That's what you did here:

```
  my $cropped_image = $image->create_scaled_image(50, 50);
```

So no matter how your image looks before, you stuff it into 50 x 50 pixels. In this case not only reducing the resolution but also changing the aspect ratio.

The image is not displayed improperly, it's displayed perfectly fine.

Comment: i really have no idea what is proper, what is not. but someone from design team showed me what resized image should look like - and they were really different -))

Comment: the most important thing in scaling is that you maintain the aspect ratio as zdim already pointed out. if you scale width and height differently you distort the image making it look weird. making it smaller while maintaining the aspect ratio will of course also make the image look weird/bad once you have too few pixels. here also display resolution and size become important. 50x50 pixels on a stamp might look ok, on a tv they will look terrible.

Comment: what should be the calculation order, to achieve best looking results? 
get width, get height, then width minus half of height, and height minus half of width and start cropping image from that coordinates?

Comment: @marmeladze no. where do these weird formulas come from? I don't even know what you want, so I can't tell you what how you can achieve "best looking results"...  do you want to crop or scale? that's two different things.